# Update Spring version in RedHat Fuse (Karaf)

Tags: spring, osgi, apache-karaf, fuseesb

I'm running JbossFuse/Karaf version 2.3.0.redhat-60024 and it comes with spring 3.1.3.RELEASE.

How to update the spring version to 3.2.4.RELEASE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring 3.1.3 is included in the features XML shipped with that Fuse ESB release, i.e. **system/org/apache/karaf/assemblies/features/standard/2.3.0.redhat-60024/standard-2.3.0.redhat-60024-features.xml**

A newer version of that features XML (not redhat specific) contains the features definitions for Spring 3.2.4, see [standard-2.3.3-features.xml](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/karaf/assemblies/features/standard/2.3.3/standard-2.3.3-features.xml).

The easiest way to install Spring 3.2.4 libraries then would be:

- features:addurl mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/standard/2.3.3/xml/features
- features:install spring/3.2.4.RELEASE

Another option is to simply copy & paste the  items you want from that file and add them to a new features XML, or append to one of the ones already included with Fuse ESB under the **system** directory. See [here](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/DeployFeatures-Create.html) for more information about creating your own features XML file.